# Looking for Children's Sci Fi Novel about a Kid Whose Family Is Able to Create Planets

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, soft-sci-fi

I'm trying to find the title of a book I read in middle school, around 2015.
I read about the first 20-30 pages, so I only remember a few details from it.

I think the plot was something like the main character, a kid around 14 years old, had to rebuild a planet (maybe Earth, I don’t remember).

The main character was jealous of his older brother, because he was very powerful or something. I think his brother built planets.

One of the things I remember happening was a female friend of his flirted with his brother, and he was upset, and she apologized.

I think the cover of the book was the main character sitting in space, looking at a book titled "How To Build a Planet", or something similar, and tapping his head confused.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this ***[Pi in the Sky](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15848896-pi-in-the-sky)*** (2013) by Wendy Mass...?

> **Joss is the seventh son of the Supreme Overlord of the Universe. His older brothers help his dad rule the cosmos,** but all Joss gets to do is deliver pies. That's right: pies. Of course, these pies actually hold the secrets of the universe between their buttery crusts, but they're still pies.
>
> Joss is happy to let his older brothers shine. He has plenty to keep his hands full: attempting to improve his bowling score; listening to his best friend, Kal, try (and fail) to play the drums; and exploring his ever-changing home, The Realms. But **when Earth suddenly disappears, Joss is tasked with the seemingly impossible job of bringing it back.** With the help of Annika, an outspoken girl from Earth, he embarks on the adventure of a lifetime...and learns that the universe is an even stranger place than he'd imagined.
>
> [image: Front cover of "Pi in the Sky" (2013) by Wendy Mass.]

From a [review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/wendy-mass/pi-sky/):

> **Joss is 13 (well, “more like a few billion and thirteen”) and lives in The Realms, a huge place “inside what you call dark matter.” As seventh son of the Supreme Overlord of the Universe, Joss’ job is to deliver pies.** He only partially understands why it matters—after his deliveries, “[s]omehow the Powers That Be distribute the pies to the far reaches of the universe, wherever new star systems are forming”—but he understands the rule (like Star Trek’s Prime Directive) that The Realms “never interfere with the planets’ natural evolution.” That said, if any planetary life-form sees The Realms, the penalty is “immediate disintegration of the entire planet.” Yet **when human Annika Klutzman spots a Realms pie-baker through a telescope, the PTB don’t demolish Earth—they rip it “out of the space-time continuum” so it never existed (sort of). Annika herself materializes inexplicably in The Realms, where she and Joss labor to rebuild Earth’s solar system.** Chapters open with tantalizing quotes from the likes of Stephen Hawking, Neil deGrasse Tyson and, of course, Carl Sagan: “If you wish to make an apple pie from scratch, you must first invent the universe.”